# how to use the return values of a query within the store procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am using Oracle and I want to define a store procedure as below, basically it will check whether the passed in p_id is null, if null then generate an id using sequence for table_1, otherwise use the p_id passed in.

tbl_ids_type is a nest table type I defined, which contains numeric ids.

what I want to do is in the LOOP part, before inserting into table_2, I want to query table_2 as `select name1, name2 from table_2 where s_id = p_id_list(i)`, that's because the record with that specific s_id may already exist in the table and I want to re-use the name1 and name2 values.

How can I do that?

```
procedure save
(
    p_id                         number default null,
    p_name                       varchar2 default null,
    p_id_list                    tbl_ids_type default null,
    p_user_id                    number default null
)
is
    tmp_id numeric;
begin
    if p_id is null then
        tmp_id := seq_1.nextval;
        insert into table_1 (
            id,
            name,
            original_id,
            user_id,
            )
        values(
            tmp_id, 
            p_name,
            -1,
            p_user_id,
        for i in 1 .. p_id_list.COUNT
        LOOP              
            insert into table_2(
                s_id,
                id,
                name1,
                name2,
                user_id
                )
            values (p_id_list(i), tmp_id, 'test_name1', 'test_name2', p_user_id);
        END LOOP;
    else
        delete from table_1 where id = p_id and user_id = p_user_id;
        delete from table_2 where id = p_id and user_id = p_user_id;
        insert into table_1 (
            id,
            name,
            original_id,
            user_id,
            )
        values(
            p_id, 
            p_name,
            '-1',
            p_user_id,
        for i in 1 .. p_id_list.COUNT
        LOOP
            insert into table_2(
                s_id,
                id,
                name1,
                name2,
                user_id
                )
            values (p_id_list(i), p_id, 'test_name1', 'test_name2', p_user_id);
        END LOOP;          
    end if;
end save_report;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your LOOP statement, just run that query and if you find values, store them in a variable. So you would add something like

```
BEGIN
 select name1, name2
  into l_name_1, l_name_2
  from table_2 
 where s_id = p_id_list(i);
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
 THEN
 l_name_1 := 'Some Default';
 l_name_2 := 'or maybe Null';
END;
```

Then you would just change your insert statement to

```
insert into table_2(
            s_id,
            id,
            name1,
            name2,
            user_id
            )
        values (p_id_list(i), tmp_id, l_name_1, l_name_2, p_user_id);
```

You may also want to add a handler for TOO_MANY_ROWS in that anonymous block.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You're looking for INTO keyword

```
l_name1 VARCHAR := NULL
l_name2 VARCHAR := NULL

for i in 1 .. p_id_list.COUNT
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            select name1, name2 INTO l_name1, l_name2 from table_2 where s_id = p_id_list(i)
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN_NO_DATA_FOUND
                //Set l_name1 and l_name2 to what you want to
        END
        insert into table_2(
                s_id,
                id,
                name1,
                name2,
                user_id
                ) values (p_id_list(i), p_id, 'test_name1', 'test_name2', p_user_id);
```

Please let  me know in case you think i am missing something.